# my app is replacing the new product for the old one in my mongoDb collection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

### I'm looking for help :) because I am having problems when I add a new product to my Mongo database because is replacing the old product

This is a Spring Boot Web Application, it's about a supermarket product database Form

**the table before a new Product**
[image: table before new product]

I want to add a new Product to the database

[image]

so I click on send the information

**The table after i sent a new Product**

[image]

the information is replaced and i don't want that :(

---

so this is my code
@Service
productoServicioImplement.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ProductoServicioImplement implements ProductoServicio2{
    
    @Autowired
    ProductosRepository productosRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Producto> getAll() {
        return productosRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void addProducto(String stock, String nombre, String codigo, Double precio , categoriaProducto categoriaproducto) {
        Producto p;
        p = new Producto(Integer.SIZE, stock, nombre, codigo, precio, categoriaproducto);
        productosRepository.save(p);

    }

    @Override
    public void addProducto(Producto producto) {
        productosRepository.save(producto);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateProducto(Producto producto) {
        productosRepository.save(producto);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteProducto(Integer id) {
        Optional<Producto> producto = productosRepository.findById(id.toString());
        if (producto.isPresent()) {
            productosRepository.deleteById(id.toString());
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public Producto guardar(Producto producto) {
        return productosRepository.save(producto);
    }
    
    public boolean borrar(Producto producto) {
        try {
            productosRepository.delete(producto);
            return true;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public Producto actualizar(Producto producto) {
        return productosRepository.save(producto);
    }
    
    public Optional<Producto> consultarPorId(Producto producto) {
        return productosRepository.findById(producto.getId().toString());
    }
    
    public List<Producto>consultarTodos() {
        return productosRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Producto getProductoById(Integer id) {
        Producto p = new Producto();
        if(Objects.equals(p.getId(), id)){
            
        }
        return p;
    }
    
}
```

Product.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Entity

@Document(collection = "productos")
@Table (name = "productos")
public class Producto implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "idProduct")
    @javax.persistence.Id
    private Integer id;
    @Column (name = "stock")
    private String stock;
    @Column (name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column (name = "codigo")
    private String codigo;
    @Column (name = "precio")
    private Double precio;
    @Column (name = "categoriaproducto")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoriaproducto")
    private categoriaProducto categoriaproducto;
    
    
    
    
   
    public Producto(){
     
    }
    public Producto(Integer idd,String stockc, String nom, String cod, Double prec,categoriaProducto cgprod){
        super();
        this.id = idd;
        this.stock = stockc;
        this.nombre = nom;
        this.codigo = cod;
        this.precio= prec;
        this.categoriaproducto=cgprod;
    }
    
    
    public Producto (Producto producto){
        super();
        this.id = producto.id;
        this.stock = producto.stock;
        this.nombre = producto.nombre;
        this.codigo = producto.codigo;
        this.precio = producto.precio;
        this.categoriaproducto = categoriaProducto.perecibles;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

  

    public String getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(String stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    

    
    

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(Double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public categoriaProducto getCategoriaproducto() {
        return categoriaproducto;
    }

    public void setCategoriaproducto(categoriaProducto categoriaproducto) {
        this.categoriaproducto = categoriaproducto;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format(
        "Producto[stock =%s , nombre ='%s',codigo = '%s',precio =%s ,categoriaproducto = '%s' ]",
                stock,nombre,codigo,precio, categoriaproducto);
        
    }
}
```

**If more of my code is needed to help, be free to ask me :)**

Answer (score 0):

**continuation

this is the service Interface

```
import java.util.List;


public interface ProductoServicio2  {
    
    
    List<Producto> getAll();

    Producto getProductoById(Integer id);

    void addProducto(String stock, String nombre, String codigo, Double precio, categoriaProducto categoriaproducto);

    void addProducto(Producto producto);

    void updateProducto(Producto producto);

    void deleteProducto(Integer id);
}
```

The Product controller

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.measure.quantity.Mass;
import static javax.measure.unit.SI.KILOGRAM;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.jscience.physics.amount.Amount;
import org.jscience.physics.model.RelativisticModel;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    

//@RestController

@Controller
public class ProductosController {
   
    @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    ProductoServicioImplement serviceProd;

  
    
    //add producto
    @GetMapping (value = "/Producto")
    public String addProduct (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("Producto", new Producto ());
        return "Producto";
        

    }

    @GetMapping (value = "/deleteProducto")
    public String deleteProduct (Model model, @RequestParam Integer id) {
        serviceProd.deleteProducto(id);
        return "redirect:/list-productos";

    }

    @GetMapping (value = "/updateProducto")
    public String updateProducto (Model model, @RequestParam Integer id) {
        Producto producto = serviceProd.getProductoById(id);
        model.addAttribute("productoup", producto);
        return "productoup";

    }
     //add producto
     @PostMapping (value = "/Producto")
    public String addProducto (@ModelAttribute Producto Producto,Model model, String stock, String nombre, String codigo, Double precio, categoriaProducto categoriaproducto ) {
        serviceProd.addProducto(stock, nombre, codigo, precio, categoriaproducto);
        model.addAttribute("Producto",Producto);
        return "result";

    }
    
    


    @PostMapping (value = "/updateProducto")
    public String updateProducto (Model model, Producto producto) {
        serviceProd.updateProducto(producto);
        return "redirect:/list-productos";

    }

    
    
    
//    @RequestMapping(value = "/guardar", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
//          consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
//          produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
//  public @ResponseBody Producto guardar(@RequestBody Producto entity) {
//      return serviceProd.guardar(entity);
//  }
//        
//    @RequestMapping(value = "/borrar", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
//          consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
//          produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
//  public @ResponseBody boolean borrar(@RequestBody Producto entity) {
//      return serviceProd.borrar(entity);
//  }
//  
//  @RequestMapping(value = "/actualizar", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
//          consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
//          produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
//  public @ResponseBody Producto actualizar(@RequestBody Producto entity) {
//      return serviceProd.actualizar(entity);
//  }
//  
//  @RequestMapping(value = "/consultarPorId", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
//          consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
//          produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
//  public @ResponseBody Producto consultarPorId(@RequestBody Producto entity) {
//      return serviceProd.consultarPorId(entity);
//  }
//  
//  @RequestMapping(value = "/consultarTodos", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
//          consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
//          produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
//  public @ResponseBody List<Producto> consultarTodos() {
//      return serviceProd.consultarTodos();
//  }
    
   

      @RequestMapping("/")
        String index() {
         return "index";
  }
  
  @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String hello(Map<String, Object> model) {
        RelativisticModel.select();
        String energy = System.getenv().get("ENERGY");
         if (energy == null) {
           energy = "12 GeV";
        }
     Amount<Mass> m = Amount.valueOf(energy).to(KILOGRAM);
     model.put("science", "E=mc^2: " + energy + " = "  + m.toString());
    return "hello";
}




  @RequestMapping("/db")
  String db(Map<String, Object> model) {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
      Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
      stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticks (tick timestamp)");
      stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ticks VALUES (now())");
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT tick FROM ticks");

      ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
      while (rs.next()) {
        output.add("Read from DB: " + rs.getTimestamp("tick"));
      }

      model.put("records", output);
      return "db";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      model.put("message", e.getMessage());
      return "error";
    }
  }
 
}
```